# grep from beginning of found word to end of word

Tags: grep

I am trying to grep the output of a command that outputs unknown text and a directory per line. Below is an example of what I mean:

```
.MHuj.5.. /var/log/messages
```

The text and directory may be different from time to time or system to system. All I want to do though is be able to grep the directory out and send it to a variable.

I have looked around but cannot figure out how to grep to the end of a word. I know I can start the search phrase looking for a "/", but I don't know how to tell grep to stop at the end of the word, or if it will consider the next "/" a new word or not. The directories listed could change, so I can't assume the same amount of directories will be listed each time. In some cases, there will be multiple lines listed and each will have a directory list in it's output. Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your directory paths does not have spaces then you can do:

```
$ echo '.MHuj.5.. /var/log/messages' | awk '{print $NF}'
/var/log/messages
```

Comment: I piped the output of the command to awk '{print $NF}' and it successfully found the directory. It also added a new blank line to the output though. Is there a way to get output of your awk command without appending a new line to the bottom of the output? Thanks!

Comment: @user2569472 Try `awk '$NF~/\//{print $NF}'`

Comment: @djf I think it was 14 seconds or something!! :)

Comment: @JS웃 my old English teacher would say: great minds think alike ; )

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from a single example whether we can generalize that e.g. the first occurrence of a slash marks the beginning of the data you want to extract. If that holds, try

```
grep -o '/.*' file
```

To fetch everything after the last space, try

```
grep -o '[^ ]*$' file
```

For more advanced pattern matching and extraction, maybe look at `sed`, or Awk or Perl or Python.

Answer (score 0):

Your line can be described as:

```
^\S+\s+(\S+)$
```

That's assuming whitespace is your delimiter between the random text and the directory.  It simply separates the whitespace from the non-whitespace and captures the second part.

Or you might want to look into the word boundary character class: `\b`.

Comment: Basic POSIX `grep` doesn't support these Perl patterns, but if you have `grep -P`, more power to you.

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work. The command ran, but there was no output.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said to use grep, but I can't help to mention that this is trivially done using awk:

```
awk '{ print $NF }' input.txt
```

This is assuming that a whitespace is the delimiter and that the path does not contain any whitespaces.